# Three.js, doesn't show correctly obj file

Tags: 3d, three.js, texture-mapping

We are working on 3d object texturing web application..

In the sample, we use 3d phone obj file with uv mapping.

But it doesnt seams correctly. When we open with 3d software blender and texture the obj file, it shows correctly.

Can the problem originated from Vertex or Normals?

Sample url:
http://www.baskiburada.com/viewer/viewer.html

Comment: 1.You have to show what it should look like. 2. You appear to have many back-to-back faces. Was that intentional?

Comment: 1. It should look like this.. It must have solid faces. [link](http://tinypic.com/r/2gtp4ip/8)

Comment: I dont know, what is back to back faces? are there 2 different faces? We didnt create this obj. And I dont know much about 3d designing.

Comment: You are going to have to study to learn the basics. You can do that by creating your own models. There is apparently something wrong with the model you are using.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to get a bit more of an understanding of the data you're trying to load and what it represents. But as for how to work with Obj files with three.js, pPerhaps go take a look at the code examples from the book Learning Three.js which are available on Github. Specifically Ch09.06 and Ch09.07: https://github.com/josdirksen/learning-threejs/tree/master/chapter-08. It contains full examples of how to load Obj files with textures.

Answer (score 0):

Good day to you, you are using r61 of the Three.js library and your model file is non-triangulated. What's happening is the "squares" that make up your mesh are being automatically split into "triangles" and obviously having a deleterious effect. Have your modeler triangulate and verify normals before sending the asset to production as it were.